# JTable mouse listener on row example

Tags: java, swing

I've taken this code from another question and was hoping someone could clarify a couple of points:

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        int r = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        if (r >= 0 && r < table.getRowCount()) {
            table.setRowSelectionInterval(r, r);
        } else {
            table.clearSelection();
        }

        int rowindex = table.getSelectedRow();
        if (rowindex < 0)
            return;
        if (e.isPopupTrigger() && e.getComponent() instanceof JTable ) {
            JPopupMenu popup = createYourPopUp();
            popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }
});
```

i understand that the line that defines 'r' gets the row at the mouse event point. but why is 'rowindex' initialised using table.getSelectedRow()? why not just use the variable 'r'. aren't they the same thing?

also - i'm confused by e.isPopupTrigger(). i read the documentation, and it refers to it as returning whether the mouseevent is the trigger for the popup.... the trick is obviously in the name - but i'm unsure of what conditions make it true or false (especially as popup.show(), whose first parameter is the invoker, is inside the if statement).

sorry for the confusion, i just don't want to blindly copy the code!

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but why is 'rowindex' initialised using table.getSelectedRow()? why not just use the variable 'r'.

The code is checking to see if the mouse point is after the last row in the table. This can happen when you use:

```
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

and your table data doesn't completely fill all the rows in the viewport of the scrollpane.

So if you click after the last row the `rowAtPoint(...)` method will return -1, which will be different than the row returned by `getSelectedRow()`.

This will cause the row selection to be removed.

Now you can use the getSelectedRow() method to determine if you have a selected row and therefore display the popup.

> i'm confused by e.isPopupTrigger().

The MouseEvent used to display the popup can be different for different platforms.

Comment: edited - i'm just rereading your answer, thanks for the quick reply though

Comment: ah, thanks for the additional info - I get the two variables now.

RE the isPopupTrigger() - i still have no idea what it even is on any platform. from my (naive) view it looks like the only thing that denotes that the mouseevent is related to the popup is the body of the if statement. which doesn't make sense given the if blocks condition.

Comment: @NickW, see updated answer, which I hope better explains why the rowAtPoint() and getSelectedRow() can return different values.

Comment: thanks, yeah the update helped. but i'm still unsure on isPopupTrigger(). what would make a MouseEvent not be a popup trigger? i assume the name is confusing me and it's not something i have to be concerned about when implementing the listener.

Comment: @NickW, on Windows you typically use the right mouse button to display the popup. On a Mac I believe it is different. That is why you use that method. The method will determine if the user is using the correct event to trigger the popup, so you don't have to worry what platform your code is running on.

Comment: yeah, i was trying to confuse myself. perfect, thanks.

Comment: it seems e.isPopupTrigger() won't return true for windows unless called from the mouseReleased() method. so i used this workaround rather than implement both mouseReleased() and mousePressed():

    e.isPopupTrigger() || e.getButton() == e.BUTTON3

which seemed to work

Comment: @NickW, Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Bringing Up a Popup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for a better implementation of your MouseListener.